# How to specify the controller name if two controllers have same RequestMapping path value?

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags, spring-4

There are 2 controllers having same @RequestMapping value :

```
package com.ambre.hib.controller;
@Controller
public class AppointmentsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        return new AppointmentForm();
    }
}

package com.ambre.hib.controller;
@Controller
public class ClientsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ClientForm getNewForm() {
        return new ClientForm();
    }
}
```

So the 2 controllers have same "/new" action.

Now from a jsp page I want to target a link to the "/new" action of the second controller : `<a href="<c:url value='/new' />"><img src="resources/images/plus.png" /></a>`

This writing is ambiguous because Spring does not know into which controller to look ! So how to specify the controller name in the link target ?

Comment: You cannot have 2 controllers on the same url. The url mapping has to be different.

Comment: Declare one controller and use if else condition, that would be better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to have two or more controller methods with the same @RequestMapping. The dispatcher won't know wich method to call.

You could set a base request mapping for each controller:

```
package com.ambre.hib.controller;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/appointments")
public class AppointmentsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public AppointmentForm getNewForm() {
        return new AppointmentForm();
    }
}

package com.ambre.hib.controller;
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clients")
public class ClientsController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ClientForm getNewForm() {
        return new ClientForm();
    }
}
```

If so, the way of calling each would be `<a href="<c:url value='/appointments/new' />">` for the first controller and 
`<a href="<c:url value='/clients/new' />">` for the second

Answer (score -1):

You need to narrow down the request using the "params" option. For example

```
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/fetch", params = {"id=100"})
    public String getInfo1(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        System.out.println("Inside getInfo1");
        return "success";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/fetch", params = {"id=200"})
    public String getInfo2(@RequestParam("id") String id) {
        System.out.println("Inside getInfo2");
        return "success";
    }
}
```

When you access the URL /fetch?id=100 , method getInfo1() is called. When you access URL /fetch?id=200 , method getInfo2() is called and when you access /fetch?id=300 , HTTP Status 404 is received. In this case the "id" parameter is just another parameter which you use to narrow down the request to your preferred method in the controller.

Comment: what if there are thousands of possible values of the parameter ?!

Comment: this is not practical ! so I have to implement thousands of methods !?

Comment: What if I access url only using /fetch without passing any param?

Comment: @VimalBera obviously it won't work ! that's why you need you use params to narrow down the requset

Comment: Ideally param should be used to pass any data, and not to distinguish controller pattern. That's what I was suggesting.

Comment: Although this may not meet the OP's requirements, this answer helped me realise that you *can* have two different controller methods on the same URL as long as they have different sets of params, like `@GetMapping()` to return all and `@GetMapping(params = { "perPage", "page" })` to return a paged response, so thanks!